# Cordova-build error: Use of const in strict mode

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I've created a new Cordova project in VS 2015. When I'm try to run the code I'm getting the following errors in my build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestProject, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 6.1.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\safan.allauddin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\TestProject\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\safan.allauddin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\TestProject\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: TestProject
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\safan.allauddin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\TestProject
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\safan.allauddin\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Adding platform: android
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : SyntaxError: C:\Users\safan.allauddin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.1.1\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\node_modules\ip-regex\index.js:3
1>  SyntaxError C:\Users\safan.allauddin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.1.1\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\node_modules\ip-regex\index.js:3
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : const v4 = '(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?:\\.(?:25[0-
1>  const v4 = '(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?:\\.(?:25[0-
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : ^^^^^
1>  ^^^^^
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Use of const in strict mode.
1>  Use of const in strict mode.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

My node version is v11.10.0 and my npm version is 6.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I took the following steps:

Go to the following directory:

```
C:\Users\'USER'\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\'CORDOVA VERSION'\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\package.json
```

In package.json file you'll find request. Change the request to `'2.81.0'` from your version.

Comment: I have the same problem but this didn't not change the result. Curious if there is any more information about what might be happening?

Comment: What node and npm version are you using?

Comment: npm is 5.6, Node is 8.9.4

Comment: Try locking your node and npm to an older verison (I am using node v4.6.0 and npm v2.8.4)

Comment: Thanks, no luck unfortunately. I downloaded 4.6.0 and pointed both my $PATH and Visual Studio (Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management) to that directory and made sure it was listed at the top so it would take precedence. Same error...

Comment: Curiously what did work was installing Visual Studio 2017 right over the top (I had 2015), now I seem to be working OK. Thank you again for replying I always worry about those threads with little activity. :)