# Cordova ionic 1 visual studio build failed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to mobile development, trying to build blank ionic android app on visual studio 2015. However, getting below error:

```
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Syntax Error: C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.2.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib\cookie.js:32

1>  SyntaxError C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.2.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordovalib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib\cookie.js:32

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : const punycode = require("punycode");

1>  const punycode = require("punycode");

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : ^^^^^


1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Use of const in strict mode.


1>  Use of const in strict mode.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801802/cordova-build-error-use-of-const-in-strict-mode  - Check the comment in the answer where it says upgrading visual studio to 2017 worked..
You can use Visual Studio Code instead..

Comment: Already tried this and the same error

Comment: What is your node version?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to some mismatch between versions of the npm modules (request, tough-cookie, cordova). In that case specifically you can read that is related to tough-cookie. Usually it is caused by a non deterministic use of npm modules, get a version that is stable and running and then use the npm shrinkwrap solution to your project in order to guarantee that you are using the same module versions of the initial project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).